# gedit doesn't allow typing!

Tags: m10

I am trying to use **gedit** 'app'(?) on my new M10.  While I can configure the tablet for font, color scheme, line numbers, etc. I cannot(!) get the on-screen keyboard to activate - which would let me actually create/modify a text document (**python3** program).

I couldn't find a way to run **idle3** either, but there IS a keyboard for the **term** program, so I know that the capability exists... somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that "traditional apps" do not work with the virtual keyboard. That is stated at the very end of  the aquarius m10 user manual. The same goes for libreoffice, firefox, ....